# What does OB do?

Tags: phantom-brave

I notice at times when an character or item is thrown or falls off the map there is this red sign that says OB.

I have a feeling that OB stands for Out of Bounds, at the start of a map there's a running count of how many enemies i have OBed and KOed.

Also i don't quite get what causes it as sometimes when I fall off i just get teleported to the edge, same with enemies at times like once when i was fighting Walnut in 2-3 I pushed him off with an attack thinking i could win easily but be just reappeared but there has been times where i have attached an enemy which has pushed them off the map and i get OB from it. other times like in 2-2 an enemy was throwing objects away to be OBed and they were at full health

So kinda this is 2 questions

1. What does OB do? and how is it any different from normally killing a character/item
2. What are the conditions for a character or item to OB

Answer (score 2):

1 - OB increases all map enemy levels.  OBing many monsters will cause the last few to be MUCH stronger

2 - Non-essential items cannot OB.  Not sure what items this includes, but the boss cannot be OBed.